# How to apply a distortion filter for the UIImage?

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing

I need to apply distortion image effect for uiimage? I dont know where i can get a complete algorithm or examples? Please help me out

Comment: Maybe custom mask can help? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101

Comment: No this not what i;m looking for

Comment: @dpart Check GIMP or ImageMagick source... ImageMagick also provides iOS libs and maybe already does what you need. If you need help with getting image data on iOS, ping and I'll gladly help.

Comment: @TheBlack Yes please provide me correct code. I'm getting the image date using this way. I'm creating CGImageRef from my UIImage, then using this function to retrieve data CGDataProviderCopyData() and after that i'm getting pointer to my pixel data CFDataGetBytePtr(). But when i want to create uiimage from this data i'm getting an issue. My image turns in blue hue. I dont know why this happening

Comment: @dpart Here: http://pastebin.com/W90pDCW3

Comment: I need to achive effect like shown here [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ru9ObflVeRU&feature=player_embedded)

Comment: @TheBlack Thank you i'll try this out. I post a link in my previous post to what i want to achive in my app.

Comment: @dpart Sorry, I don't have any experience with applying effects to image, can't help you with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could lead you to your goal :

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/photoshopframew/

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters